# Undefined variable Error when using define()

Tags: php, undefined

Using PHP 5.4 I am getting 'Notice: Undefined variable: sqliteDatabase in test.php on line 9'

Code:

```
<?php

//Set The Database Name, No Other Editing Of This File Should Be Done
 define("sqliteDatabase", "PlayerVsPlayerDatabase" );

 //Nothing Below Needs Touched
 date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

 if(!file_exists("${sqliteDatabase}.sqlite3")) {

    try {

        // Create (connect to) SQLite database in file
        $file_db = new PDO("sqlite:${sqliteDatabase}.sqlite3");
```

Comment: You probably want to use the defined constant, so just concatenate it: `constant . "string"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if(!file_exists("${sqliteDatabase}.sqlite3")) {
```

to

```
if(!file_exists(sqliteDatabase.".sqlite3")) {
```

A constant should be called without single and double quotes.